# Add additional type to object after running through a transformer function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-objects, typeorm

So I have this object that will have many entries and it is defined in the following manner:

```
/* All Items are a class of their own */
export const ENTITIES = {
  Article: Article,
  HomeFooter: HomeFooter,
};
```

[image]

Now I want to run this object through the `getRepository` function and return the following typescript types without creating a separate typescript type for just that transformer function (similar to the `ResultType` I had created below).

```js
import { HomeFooter, Article } from "../database/entity";
import { ENTITIES } from "./entities";

/* Types */
import type { DataSource, Repository } from "typeorm";


type KeyType = keyof typeof ENTITIES;

/* I want to remove this manual typing */
type ResultType = {
    Article: Repository<Article>;
    HomeFooter: Repository<HomeFooter>;
}

export function makeRepositories(dataSource: DataSource) {
  const repositories = Object.keys(ENTITIES).reduce((acc, entity) => {
    const key = entity as KeyType;
    const value = ENTITIES[key];
    acc[key] = dataSource.getRepository(value);
    return acc;
  }, {} as ResultType);

  return repositories;
}
```

The return type of `getRepository` is a generic of `Repository<T>` and not `Repository<typeof T>`

Comment: Are you just looking for a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVrq5N)? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm looking for mapped types but with a wrapper return type. I'll update the article with the actually code and may be then you can help me out.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the example to what I exactly what I need.

Comment: If this depends on typeorm then you might want to tag the question as such; if not, could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can just copy and paste into our own IDEs?  All the types and values should be self-contained so that nobody needs to either guess or look up the typings.